# Setting up Rhodes environment with Ruby on Rails already installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rhodes, rhomobile

I am learning and have already set up a Ruby on Rails environment based on [Hartl's book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). I would also like to set up a Rhodes environment for mobile app development.

How would I set up Rhodes after having set up Ruby on Rails, without messing up my Ruby on Rails environment? Also, will I still need RhoSync if I have SQLite3 (or MySQL) with WEBrick (or Apache)?

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 (I will use RhoHub for the compiles)

NOTE: I have found [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692324) on the Ubuntu Forum but they are not exactly what I'm looking for, as I am using ruby with RVM

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching and reading the [Rhomobile book](http://www.packtpub.com/build-enterprise-mobile-web-application-using-rhomobile-beginners-guide/book) that was just released, if you have a Ruby on Rails environment, all you need to do is:

- install the "Rhodes" gem
- install the "Rhosync" gem
- the SDK of the phone you wish to develop for (this also depends on your dev machine)

RhoSync is a server on the phone which talks to whatever backend you need, whether it is your own server/DB or another like Heroku (the book gives a Heroku example). This means your DB and Server are not an issue.

A friendly note to all, I am a beginner so I could stand under correction. I only answered with my findings as not many people had answered this questions, so I assumed not many people knew the answer.

Hope this helps other beginners, and feel free to correct my findings if it's needed.